# Uncaught TypeError: carouselWithDescription.caroufredsel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**This is how my scripts in homepage look like . But i keep getting the error Uncaught TypeError: carouselWithDescription.caroufredsel is not a function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#DownloadApp").click(function () {

        fbq('track', 'Lead');
    });
</script>

<!-- Bootstrap Libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/vendors/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Masonry Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/vendors/isotope/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/vendors/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<!-- Revolution Slider jQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/vendors/revolution-slider/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>

<!-- Quote Rotator jQuery-->
<script src="~/Content/NewHomePage/vendors/quote-rotator/js/jquery.quoterotator.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Inview Plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/vendors/inview/jquery.inview.js"></script>

<!-- Magnific Popup Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/vendors/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<!-- CarouFredSel Plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/vendors/carouFredSel-6.2.1/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/scripts/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/scripts/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/scripts/custom.js"></script>


<!-- Options Panel Scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/NewHomePage/scripts/_sample.js"></script>
```

Comment: try moving 'carouFredSel' up?

Comment: i have tried moving it below the both jquery acript tags but that also wont work

Comment: you have any jQuery base library added there? I am unable to see. (something like:- `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
)

Comment: Yes this lib is added
jquery-ui.min.js amd jquery.min.js

Comment: This issue was due to the fact that i had 2 jquery listed on the page .. one was getting referred from master page layout . removed that it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to multiple times listing of jquery . The page was referring master layout which was interupting the loading of some files.Removde the refference now it works fine.